# Remove redundancy while "editing" a String

Tags: java, string, char, substring, redundancy

Since strings are immutable, I'm trying to re-create it.
I need to replace one of the letters.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mat.length(); i++){
    //there's more stuff here, but that'd require a lot more explaining
    //the following don't occur at every iteration
    //mat and s are always the same length though
    if (i == s.length())
        mat = mat.substring(0, i) + s.charAt(i);
    else
        mat = mat.substring(0, i) + s.charAt(i) + mat.substring(i + 1, mat.length());
}
```

Basically altering a letter of String mat with a letter of String s at the same index.
Problem is if it's the last index, I would get an out of bounds error, so I've opted to use an if/else to take care of that.

But there's redundancy in that both conditions run the code:

```
mat = mat.substring(0, i) + s.charAt(i)
```

What's the best way to remove this redundancy?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you incrementing i ? Also it would be efficient if you used **StringBuilder** instead coz you are creating too many String.

Comment: `if (i == s.length())` then you're done – you've already iterated over all the characters of the string.

Comment: I don't think I can use StringBuilder haha, it's for school.
And Matt, but I might need to change the last character?

Comment: Your code will fail if `if (i == s.length())` evaluates true. If `i` is the string length then the subsequent `s.charAt(i)` will produce an `IndexOutOfBounds` error.

Comment: Well if there was ever a 'Doh!' moment.....

Comment: This questions title and code example are very unclear. Please provide an example of the desired input and output.

Comment: I'd drop a `StringBuilder` in there, for better scaling (depending on big you expect `mat` to become, its going to be a nightmare on your garbage collection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this (refactoring) ?

```
String optional = ""; 
if ((i != s.length()))
    optional=  mat.substring(i + 1, mat.length());

mat = mat.substring(0, i) + s.charAt(i) + optional
```

;

Comment: Haha I tried that, doesn't work since your initial re-defining of mat effectively cuts off the end.

Comment: Ah yes, I was trying to avoid using another string cause that's the same/more code.
But your solution is different......hmmm interesting.....gimme a second

Answer (score 0):

If `i=s.length()` than last index will be `i-1`;

```
if (i == s.length())
mat = mat.substring(0, i) + s.charAt(i-1);// Use i-1 instead of i.
else
mat = mat.substring(0, i) + s.charAt(i) + mat.substring(i + 1, mat.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

If value i is equals to  the length of string s.

In your code s.charAt(i) is out of the array range. The max index to use should be **i-1**, which is for the last character.

Answer (score 0):

```
pat = pat.substring(0, i) + s.charAt(i) + pat.substring(i + 1, pat.length());
```

by itself works........I'm not really sure why.....
If the change need to happen at the first letter of the String, the first clause is just "", similarly if it's the last letter......shouldn't there be an out-of-bounds exception with the i+1?

*update:*
just did a quick scratch program, as it turns out the inclusive index of the substring method does not return an out of bounds if it's only 1 past the last index.

*Example*:

```
    man ="what";

    System.out.println(man.substring(4, 4));
```

works just fine and outputs nothing.
Console doesn't even pop up on eclipse if you use just .print